# SQL, does using LIMIT 1 give perf improvement on an index

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table in Postgres has only three columns and those three columns make up the primary key. So this is index only scanning.

Will I get a performance improvement if I use LIMIT 1 in my SELECT query?

```
SELECT col2 
FROM my_table 
WHERE col1 = '1111' AND col2 = '2222' AND col3 = '3333' 
LIMIT 1;
```

vs

```
SELECT col2 
FROM my_table 
WHERE col1 = '1111' AND col2 = '2222' AND col3 = '3333';
```

Which is most performant?

Comment: If the three columns comprise the primary key, then any performance gain would probably be measured in nano-seconds (if there were one at all).

Comment: I can't see any reason why there'd be a difference in these two queries, but you can use [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-explain.htm) to verify.

Comment: Possible there is even a penalty for the `LIMIT 1` version as the DBMS has a little more to do. But if that's the case, it will as neglectable as a possible gain.

Comment: Run both queries 10000 times in a loop, measure total times and compare results, and you will see. There should not be any differences.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). The one thing that is almost universally true is that there are *no* universally true rules for writing the "most performant" code.

Comment: Just my two cents. When you add `LIMIT 1` you are applying restrictions to the optimizer (however good these restrictions are). For good or bad, the optimizer has less options where to choose from.

Comment: I am happy with these answers.  I am going to drop LIMIT 1.  I will circle back when I have ran my performance test.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you would gain much if you had many rows that match. Maybe planing time would be higher but execution time will be lower.

Comment: @YavuzSelim - they've indicated it's the primary key for the table, so it should only be return 0/1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have n number of records matching the same criteria which you have used in where clause and you need only single record among those records then keeping limit 1 will be efficient.